# Usage of a singleton service inside of a function

Tags: c#, azure-functions

Here is my startup file which has a singleton declared -

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var endPoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COSMOS_DB_CONNECTION_STRING_EMULATOR");

        var masterKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COSMOS_DB_MASTER_KEY_EMULATOR");
        builder.AddGraphQLFunction().AddQueryType<Query>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton((s) => {
            return new CosmosClient(endPoint, masterKey);
        });


    }
}
```

Now how do I use the same singleton declared above in the below function. I just have no idea what to put in here to get access to the above singleton.

```
public class Query : IQuery
{
    public Result GetUser()
    {
        
        User u = new User();
        
        return new Result
        {
            Status = 200,
            User = u,
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: You inject it. That means: add a ctor arg in `Query` of your singleton's type. With that you initialize a private readonly field of that type. Then you can use it in any member method. Given that you instanciate `Query` through DI, too, the dependency will be injected by the DI system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you will need to add a constructor to the Query class that takes a CosmosClient parameter.

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    private CosmosClient _cosmosClient;

    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var endPoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COSMOS_DB_CONNECTION_STRING_EMULATOR");
        var masterKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COSMOS_DB_MASTER_KEY_EMULATOR");

        _cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(endPoint, masterKey);

        builder.AddGraphQLFunction().AddQueryType<Query>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton((s) => _cosmosClient);
    }
}

public class Query : IQuery
{
    private readonly CosmosClient _cosmosClient;

    public Query(CosmosClient cosmosClient)
    {
        _cosmosClient = cosmosClient;
    }

    public Result GetUser()
    {
        User u = new User();

        // Use _cosmosClient to retrieve user data

        return new Result
        {
            Status = 200,
            User = u,
        };
    }
}
```

With these modifications, the Query class now has access to the singleton instance of the CosmosClient object declared in the Startup class.